# Can I play co-op multiplayer with a guest in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

If I buy one license of [Dungeon Defenders](http://dungeondefenders.com/) from the current [Humble Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/) can I play it co-operatively with my family on two or even better three PCs in the same LAN? I've heard that it supports guest play.

Comment: Note that if you do decide to buy extra copies, you'll probably want to get them through the bundle as well, because the bundle includes all DLC

Answer (score 8):

Each computer requires its own license to play, however if you have controllers you can do a split-screen up to 4 people on a single computer. This means that in order to play with 8 people on your LAN, a minimum of 2 computers is required (2 computers each with 4-person split screen).

[image]

If you want each person to have their own keyboard and mouse, each computer MUST have their own licensed copy of the game.

Comment: Can you play with two people split screen on the same computer, whilst playing online with 2 others aswell? Or are these modes set up differently?

Comment: @Shane You can split screen and still multiplayer with other computers, yes - as long as you're all playing in "Online". (I don't remember how "Local" connections work, but I presume if it's a LAN game you can still split screen and have other computers from the network.)

Comment: Sorry to revive a 'dead' question, but I've already posted to no avail.
I'm trying to get a similar setup, but I'm having issues with just split screen. It appears that all heroes are on one account, how did you get around that?